# React-Modal "Objects are not valid as a React child"?

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

Have a look at the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const OptionModal = (props)=>(
    <Modal
    isOpen={!!props.selectedOption}
    contentLabel="Selected Option"
    >
    <h1>Selected Option</h1>
    {props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}
  </Modal>
);


export default OptionModal;
```

Also selectedOption contains the randomly selected string.

When I use `{props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}` it gives the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {option}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.". Not using this my code is working properly. Please help me fix this

Comment: What does props.selectedOption contain? Is it an object? What are the properties it contains?

Comment: @G_S it is an string.It just contains the name of randomly selected option of a TODO app

Comment: Can you do a console.log(props.selectedOption) and post the result? And also can you post where you are passing the props from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
{props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}
```

this part reterned props.selectedOption if is it not null and not boolean.
so **Change it to**

```
{!!props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}
```

to convert it to boolean.

Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const OptionModal = (props)=>(
    <Modal
    isOpen={!!props.selectedOption}
    contentLabel="Selected Option"
    >
    <h1>Selected Option</h1>
    {!!props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}
  </Modal>
);


export default OptionModal;
```